# How to enable Contact to allow login on SF org - Lightning LEX

Tags: lightning-experience, contact

How to enable Contact to allow login on SF org .

I think this was available in classic but could not find in Lightning LEX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Page Layout and in Mobile and Lightnng Action, Drag and Drop **Log In To Communities as User** and **Enable Partner/Customer User** in Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experince Actions.

[image]

Src: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_networks_manage_external_users_lex.htm